# React + useState + Array + Mutation = error

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, socket.io

On function writeMessage, I need to fill the array named chat with the new messages incoming. To do so I have try three alternatives with no luck. Without mutation, they only take initalState and discard other changes. And with mutation it does not re-render itself. Any help will be appreciated.

const writeMessage = (msg) => {
       //newChat = chat.concat(msg); 
       //newChat = [...chat, msg]; this two takes inital State, but doesn not work with modified state 
       //setChat(newChat);
       chat.push(msg); //this mutates :( and works, but does not re-render itself
      }

My Code:

```js
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
  var socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3001/')
  var newChat= [];

  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
  const [chat, setChat] = useState([{msg:"Hola"},{msg:"Todo Bien?"}])

  useEffect(() => {  
    socket.on('new message', function(msg){
      writeMessage(msg)
     });
  },[])

  const writeMessage = (msg) => {
   //newChat = chat.concat(msg); 
   //newChat = [...chat, msg]; this two takes inital State, but doesn not work with modified state 
   //setChat(newChat);
   chat.push(msg); //this mutates :( and works, but does not re-render itself
  }

  const sendMessage = () => {
    if(message === ""){
      alert("Write something please");
    }else{
      socket.emit('send message', message);
      setMessage("");
    }
    console.log(chat);
}

  return (
    <div>
    <ul id="messages">{chat.map((msg, index) => <li key={index}>{msg.msg}</li>)}</ul>
      <form>
        <input id="m" autoComplete="off" value={message} onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}/>
        <button type="button" onClick={sendMessage}>Send</button>
      </form>
      
    </div>)
}

export default App
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I expect to add new Messages to the array without mutation and keeping messages sent before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using useState, you can use `prevState` and the spread operator to create a new array like this.

```
const writeMessage = (msg) => {
  setChat((prevState) => [...prevState, msg]);
}
```

With this method you don't mutate the state and the component gets rendered again.

Comment: This is the correct answer to my problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to mutate chat directly. Use `setChat` instead:

Edited: 
You should use userReducer to a not primitive value. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer

```
  const writeMessage = (msg) => {
   setChat([...chat, newChat]); // This should re-render
  }
```