# useState callback syntax doesn't update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a state declaration in my application that holds an `array` of information and can be updated by a form nested within a sub-component.

I'm using `useState`s callback syntax in order to update the data, but for some reason, despite the callback running and the state changing, it won't be updated.

This can be confirmed when checking a state change in `useEffect`; it won't output any changes with a `console.log`. However, inside the callback itself, the `console.log` will work every time (so clearly the callback is running).

This is a simplified layout of what I'm doing:

```
const MainContext = createContext();

const Parent = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    const updateData = (index, field, value) => {
        // This just updates (or initialises) an object at the specified index.
        setData(previousState => {
            let candidates = previousState;
            let candidate = candidates[index];

            if(typeof candidate !== "object"){
                candidate = {};
            }

            candidate[field] = value;
            candidates[index] = candidate;
      
            // This will run every time, and return the correct result:
            // [{
            //     example: value
            // }]
            console.log(candidates);
            return candidates;
        });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(data); // This will not run whenever the field is updated.
    }, [data]);
 
    return (
        <MainContext.Provider value={{
            dispatch: {
                updateData
            }
        }}>
            <Child />
        </MainContext.Provider>
    );
};


// Whenever a user enters data inside this components input, it should push a change
// via the dispatch.updateData method and update the array in the parent component.
const Child = () => {
    const testIndex = 1;
    return (
        <MainContext.Consumer>{({ dispatch }) => (
            <input 
                name="example" 
                placeholder="Example Field" 
                onChange={evt => dispatch.updateData(
                    testIndex, 
                    evt.target.name, 
                    evt.target.value
                )} />
        )}</MainContext.Consumer>
    );
};
```

So, what's going on here? It appears the state is being set correctly, and even if I wrap the `updateData` method into a `useCallback` with the deps set to the state hook, it will still fail to console out in the `useEffect`.

Comment: Return new instance of state::    return [...candidates], if state refererence will not be changed, useeffect will not be triggered by data.

Comment: @Oleg I'm not quite sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: In 
     updateData function, change return canditates to return [...candidates]

Comment: @Oleg That's a bit quirky. I'm surprised you cannot simply return the array as is. Care to share an answer which elaborates a bit? :-) Thank you regardless.

Comment: Read here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26253351/correct-modification-of-state-arrays-in-react-js and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57538610/react-usestate-array-mutation-error

Comment: When you update the state react checks for `currentData === dataReturnedFromSetDataCallback`. And in _Javascript_ if you do `const arr1 = [1,2,3]` and `const arr2=arr1` , no matter how you update the `arr1` your `arr2` will be same as the `arr1` since you are using same references.